Let $G$ be a finite abelian group. If $f:G\to G$ is a group homomorphism then $G = \text{im}(f^k)\oplus \ker(f^k)$ for some $k$ postive integer.

Let $G$ be a finite abelian group. If $f:G\to G$ is a group homomorphism then $G = im(f^k)\oplus ker(f^k)$ for some $k$ postive integer.

I can see that the iterated application of $f$ will produce an descending chain of kernel and an ascending chain of the images that will eventually stabilizes because $G$ is finite.
Composition of group homomorphism is a group homomorphism. For every $g$ in $G$, it can be written as the sum of an element in $ker(f^k)$ and an element of $im(f^k)$. And furthermore that their intersection is the identity. To sum it is ok, since that $g$ will be or the image or in the kernel or in both. Need to prove that eventually their intersection is trivial. Can someone help me?

why is it not valid for any k? I think it is all of G, because every element will be or in the kernel or in the image.

I see now that since they stabilize, their intersection has to be trivial at some point. But now I am also wondering if I can say that G is at least the non direct sum of the kernel and image of f

Please don't write the problem only in the title. It should be stated in the body of the post. The statement "because every element will be in the kernel or in the image." is wrong.

If you wish to find a counterexample for infinite $G$, you can take $G= \mathbb{Z} [X]$ and $\partial$ the additive group endomorphism of differentiation.

This is well known in the context of finite dimensional vector spaces

Well every injective non-surjective endomorphism works, as does every surjective non-injective endomorphism. @julio_es_sui_glace

@lhf The proof works for every object in an abelian category that is Noetherian and Artinian.

As mentioned in your question, we may find some $k$ such that $\operatorname{im}(f^k) = \operatorname{im}(f^n)$ and $\ker(f^k) = \ker(f^n)$ for all $n \ge k$.
Then $\ker(f^k) \cap \operatorname{im}(f^k) = \{0\}$ since if $x \in \ker(f^k) \cap \operatorname{im}(f^k)$, then we can let $x = f^k(y)$, and then $y \in \ker(f^{2k})$ since $f^{2k}(y) = f^k(f^k(y)) = f^k(x) = 0$. Then $y \in \ker(f^k)$ (since we assumed $k$ is large enough that $\ker$ stabilised), so $x = 0$.
Now we show $\ker(f^k) + \operatorname{im}(f^k) = G$. Since $G$ is finite, and clearly LHS is contained in RHS, it suffices to show that the size of the LHS is $|G|$.
Since $\ker(f^k) \cap \operatorname{im}(f^k) = \{0\}$, we have that (using the first isomorphism theorem):
$$\begin{align*}
|\ker(f^k) + \operatorname{im}(f^k)|
&= |\ker(f^k)| \times |\operatorname{im}(f^k)| \\
&= |\ker(f^k)| \times |G / \ker(f^k)| \\
&= |\ker(f^k)| \times |G| / |\ker(f^k)| \\
&= |G|
\end{align*}$$

Great. It clarified all my questions. Thank you.
